# â‚¹ Symbol is coming instead Rs

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting â‚¹ in invoice page instead Rs symbol. How to fix this issue in magento 1.9.1? Please help me with this

Comment: it is file encode problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files must be saved in UTF8 encoding (without boom) please ensures that all *.php and *.phtml files are saved with this encoding.

There is a lot of tools to change file encodings if you are using windows [this](http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-professional.aspx) can help.

If can identify which file(s) are wrong with notepad++ you can change it too.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I did it by adding &#8377; in Symbol instead rs in ad-min panel.